# Builder Pattern in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin world. I have a existing builder written in Java and would like to convert it to Kotlin as I am migration the project to kotlin in Android. However, the Android Studio built-in tool seems have some bugs, then converted code is not compilable. It is showing inaccessible to the variables in my `UserBuilder` class.

Here is the Java code from [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html)

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName; // required
    private final String lastName; // required
    private final int age; // optional
    private final String phone; // optional
    private final String address; // optional

    private Person(UserBuilder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.address = builder.address;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public static class UserBuilder {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;
        private int age;
        private String phone;
        private String address;

        public UserBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public UserBuilder age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder phone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder address(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }

    }
}
```

The auto converted kotlin code:

```
class Person private constructor(builder: UserBuilder) {
    val firstName: String // required
    val lastName: String // required
    val age: Int // optional
    val phone: String // optional
    val address: String // optional

    init {
        //cannot access the variables, they are private in UserBuilder
        this.firstName = builder.firstName  
        this.lastName = builder.lastName   
        this.age = builder.age
        this.phone = builder.phone
        this.address = builder.address
    }

    class UserBuilder(private val firstName: String, private val lastName: String) {
        private var age: Int = 0
        private var phone: String? = null
        private var address: String? = null

        fun age(age: Int): UserBuilder {
            this.age = age
            return this
        }

        fun phone(phone: String): UserBuilder {
            this.phone = phone
            return this
        }

        fun address(address: String): UserBuilder {
            this.address = address
            return this
        }

        fun build(): Person {
            return Person(this)
        }

    }
}
```

---

UPDATED

```
class Person private constructor(builder: UserBuilder) {
    val firstName: String // required
    val lastName: String // required
    val age: Int // optional
    val phone: String? // optional
    val address: String? // optional

    init {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName
        this.lastName = builder.lastName
        this.age = builder.age
        this.phone = builder.phone
        this.address = builder.address
    }

    class UserBuilder(internal val firstName: String, internal val lastName: String) {
        internal var age: Int = 0
        internal var phone: String? = null
        internal var address: String? = null

        fun age(age: Int): UserBuilder {
            this.age = age
            return this
        }

        fun phone(phone: String): UserBuilder {
            this.phone = phone
            return this
        }

        fun address(address: String): UserBuilder {
            this.address = address
            return this
        }

        fun build(): Person {
            return Person(this)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bad builder design that one is  coulped with another.

Comment: If you could provide a better idea, i would love to see how that works in Kotlin as I am new in Kotlin world.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm on mobile and I think kcoppock's answer  meet your needs. What I said is:"`User` shouldn't depends on `UserBuilder`", :)

Answer (score 8):

Given it's Kotlin, you can actually make this far simpler using a data class.

```
data class User(val firstName: String, 
        val lastName: String,
        val age: Int = 0,
        val phone: String? = null,
        val address: String? = null)
```

And that's it! The first two parameters are required, but if you want to specify more, you just specify them by name:

```
val user = User("John", "Doe", phone = "555-1212")
```

No builder needed!

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I understood that there are optional params support for kotlin but i would still want to have builder as my kotlin library will be used in Java.

Comment: That doesn't really replace the builder pattern.

Comment: @Ascorbin depends on what you need the builder for. If you need to capture a builder reference and work with one directly, then this may not work for you. If you're just using the builder to provide default values from the Java side and/or simplify the constructor, then this does essentially serve as a replacement.

Comment: Also take a look at https://android.jlelse.eu/writing-java-friendly-kotlin-code-c408b24fb4e which shows how to use @JvmOverloads constructor to generate every permutation of constructors you need in Java, if you're okay with changing from a Java Builder to just calling a single constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple conversion as you did before.

Now you will see that `UserBuilder` will has `internal` access modifier just remove this and add public or whatever your requirement is.

---

#### Edit1

Ok, `internal` keyword is not there in your `Kotlin` code, I overlooked that while checking your code.

So now what you need to do is create an object in `Person` class and put your `UserBuilder` class in there.

Check following code:

```
class Person private constructor(builder: Builder.UserBuilder) {
    val firstName: String // required
    val lastName: String // required
    val age: Int // optional
    val phone: String // optional
    val address: String // optional

init {
    //cannot access the variables, they are private in UserBuilder
    this.firstName = builder.firstName  
    this.lastName = builder.lastName   
    this.age = builder.age
    this.phone = builder.phone
    this.address = builder.address
}
object Builder {
class UserBuilder(private val firstName: String, private val lastName: String) {
    private var age: Int = 0
    private var phone: String? = null
    private var address: String? = null

    fun age(age: Int): UserBuilder {
        this.age = age
        return this
    }

    fun phone(phone: String): UserBuilder {
        this.phone = phone
        return this
    }

    fun address(address: String): UserBuilder {
        this.address = address
        return this
    }

    fun build(): Person {
        return Person(this)
    }

}
}
}
```

This should work as in your Java code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: your solution seems still not working for me. Its shows the same accessibility error. I end up change the instance variables in `UserBuilder` to internal for `Person` to access it. I forgot to mention that the method will be called from other modules.

Comment: I have checked, above code its working properly from different module. Just recheck if you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person private constructor(builder: UserBuilder) {
val firstName: String // required
val lastName: String // required
val age: Int // optional
val phone: String // optional
val address: String // optional

init {
    this.firstName = builder.firstName  
    this.lastName = builder.lastName   
    this.age = builder.age
    this.phone = builder.phone
    this.address = builder.address
}

class UserBuilder(private val _firstName: String, private val _lastName: String) {
    private var _age: Int = 0
    private var _phone: String? = null
    private var _address: String? = null

    var firstName: String
        get() = this._firstName
    var lastName: String
        get() = this._lastName
    var age: Int = 0
        get() = this._age
    var phone: String? = null
        get() = this._phone
    var address: String? = null
        get() = this._address

    fun age(age: Int): UserBuilder {
        this._age = age
        return this
    }

    fun phone(phone: String): UserBuilder {
        this._phone = phone
        return this
    }

    fun address(address: String): UserBuilder {
        this._address = address
        return this
    }

    fun build(): Person {
        return Person(this)
    }

}
```

}

Using custom getters in this way can solve the private access modifier problem.